# Why is agile all about the test-driven development (TDD) and not development-driven test (DDT)?

Tags: agile, tdd, development-methodologies

So I am new to agile, but not [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). My professors in college were all about the idea of tests then code then tests. I am not sure I understand why. From my perspective it is a lot of upfront cost that will most likely be changed as your code evolves.

This is how I imagine TDD and why it confuses me. If I were to build a house as a TDD contractor.

1. Give me all of your specs (stories).
2. Get approval on the specs.
3. Break down all the specs into inspection I think I will need (see into the future).
4. Call an inspector to look at those points and tell me right now I am failing the inspection (gee thanks).
5. Start building the house.
6. Call the inspector back out daily (passing 2/100).
7. Oh shoot, there was an issue with my understanding and now I need to add 9 more inspection and change 27 of them.
8. Call inspector passing 1/109.
9. Damn it. Why doesn't the inspector like this one... oh I updated that method name...
10. Build some more.
11. UGGGGHHHH MORE CHANGES let me update the damn inspector. Oh I am failing no s**t.
12. Am I done yet?

Okay, that may be outlandish, but I just do not see how I should know all my methods and how things will work until my code is there. 99% of the time I have to go back and update a unit test any ways and add more as I go. It just seems backwards.

What seems more appropriate is DDT or development-driven testing which is a thing the community has all but forgotten about it seems.

From my understanding DDT for a house would look like:

1. Give me all of your specs (stories).
2. Get approval on the specs and break them out.
3. Start a unit (the foundation).
4. Take notes (comments) of some tricky logic.
5. At the end before beginning the next unit have the inspection (create a test).
6. Fix any issue found and inspect again.
7. Approved this unit move onto the next.

If we are all being honest doesn't that sound more human and centered on the developer and business? It seems like changes can be made faster and without the overhead TDD seems to create.

Comment: The glaring disconnect for me is the idea that you can have 100+ failing tests before writing the code that starts passing them. As @Telastyn says, there should be no more than a few failing tests at a time. "Tests then Code then Test" doesn't mean writing _all_ of the app's tests before writing any code.

Comment: Your edit didn't really add any value to the question.  If you don't like the way people are answering, ask for clarification in the comments of the answer, not in a billboard at the top of your question.  Or, find a way to word your actual question better.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I find it helpful to state I am not incapable of making a distinction between the world and code. The fact that it is called out in every answer does not help me better understand anything. To update my question at this point would confuse the meaning of the answer already here. I do admit it was not needed as a billboard though.

Comment: Metaphors are an antipattern! People will spend more time explaining why your metaphor does not fit the subject, rather than addressing your actual concern. In this case your actual concern seem to be you think you have to write *all* tests up front.

Comment: @JacquesB agreed that was my issue but I only just came to that realization. I wouldn't have known to ask about that. I worded it the best way I knew how.

Comment: What you describe secondly, as DDT is much closer to how TDD is supposed to work. Only, you know, test first.

Comment: @RubberDuck I am catching onto that. This is bringing me back to the idea for sure.

Comment: As a side-note here, TDD is commonly used in agile projects but I think it's important to distinguish between agile project management and agile development practices.  There isn't a very strong relationship between the two.  You can use most agile development practices regardless of the project methodology and vice-versa.  It's often forgotten that agile, at it 's core, is really about adapting your approach as needed to achieve the best result and not about a prescriptive list of things you must do.  In other words, Agile != Scrum + TDD.

Comment: For the record, comparing software development to building a house is pointless. The studies have been done. The results are in. The answer is clear. You simply do not build software the same way you build a house. The. Two. Are. Different.

Comment: Agile is all about fast feedback loops, TDD is just one particular type of feedback loop

Comment: The "Write Tests before the code" essentially mean you have to design the API up front - or you couldn't write the test.  In my experience this typically mean that the resulting API's are better because you write what you need, instead of exposing what you wrote.

Comment: Basically people following Agile follow TDD too because they are recent practices that came around the same time, that doesn't mean both of them can't exist independantly.

Comment: @Stargazer712: heh. And the TDD way to build a house would be like: "it needs at least one brick", put a brick down, "great, it has a brick!". Add a new test, "it needs at least two bricks", test fails, add a brick, re-run tests, "great, it has two bricks!". Add a new test...

Comment: @SteveJessop That would have been my assumption too but I think something more accurate is that a method for `add_brick(int count)` is needed create the test, fail it, create method test it. Now we need a method `add_wall()` or `add_foundation` each use the above method with some calculation and angles. Write the test for that and ta-da.

Comment: "Why is agile all about TDD?"  It's not.  http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html

Comment: I think this question takes as its premise that all, or nearly all, professionals agree on TDD, which simply isn't true.

Comment: @Casey If anything it would imply that agile is mostly about TDD which I know is not the case. But when starting out in agile without decades of experience under your belt and Googling agile it is fair assumption to make based on what is returned. The question was more about the benefits of TDD and why others are not more apparent when starting out.

Comment: Designing something to be tested results in much better separation of concerns so that things actually can be tested.

Comment: The critical factors (in software) are speed, and (in)visibility. You can build (compile) your software in seconds, but no one else can see it or what it does, espescially if it's part of a large project. Houses take weeks, but progress can be seen easily. Agile is a response to the invisibility issue. Testing is a solution based on the speed. Together they provide a mechanism to ensure that what you built is what was wanted and that it works. House building has other issues, so uses different solutions (architect plans & drawings, Building standards, codes and inspections; tidy worksites).

Comment: An aspect of this question that I don't believe has been mentioned yet is that in your analogy, calling out the inspector and asking them to repeat their inspection is essentially free, in both time and material cost.

Yes, the rest of it is tenuous, as most responders have addressed already.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

One of the benefits of a TDD approach is only realised when you also do emergent design.

So in your first analogy, you wouldn't write 100 tests, as there's no possible way that you'll know what your software will look like.

You write one test. You run it. It fails. You write the smallest unit of code to make your test pass. Then you run your test again. It passes.

Now write the next test, repeating the process above.

This might seem like a wasteful approach at the very beginning, when it's obvious what your code is meant to do, but the great thing with this approach is your test coverage is always high, and the code design is cleaner this way.

As a method, it goes hand-in-hand with pair programming; one pair writes the test, the next writes the code to make it pass, then writes the next test, and so on.

I even use this approach when writing a new class; the first test is a call to initiate the class constructor. But I haven't yet written the class, so it fails. Next I write the simple, empty class, and my first test passes.

Once you get into the mindset, it is very difficult to not be in it and code the "old fashioned" way.

I'd recommend working in a good Agile environment to learn this, or reading a few good Agile books (Clean Code and Clean Coder are both very good) to better understand.

Comment: First thank you for not calling me outfor using a real world example. This was an eye opener. I think my biggest grip was because my professor had us commit tests first of everything we planned to do which seems wrong based on your depiction.

Comment: The term "Emergent Design" makes it sound like you can grow a software design by making tests pass.  You can't.

Comment: All the other answers here were great and really help me understand this topic. I chose this one though because it helped me get past the biggest obstacle which was write everything up-front. This really shows how the iterations happen.

Comment: @nerdlyist: Don't forget about design, though.  You still need to design software; good design doesn't just naturally emerge from red-green-refactor.  TDD encourages good design, but it doesn't create it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes I do admit that was left out as a topic but in my example the "specs" would be a vetted design plan. Not to say that this does not continually change but my lack of understanding was mostly in the use of TDD not planning and design that make sense to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I completely disagree with your "*The term "Emergent Design" makes it sound like you can grow a software design by making tests pass. You can't*" statement. Having done just that on a number of occasions, I can assure you it can be done.

Comment: @DavidArno: Do you begin with a requirements specification in hand?  How do you translate that specification into a sensible architecture?  Do you reinvent it each time with tests, or do you have previous architectural principles in mind?  Nobody does this in the blind; there's nothing at all magical about writing your tests first, other than it forces you to make your code more testable.

Comment: @nerdlyist I don't want to get caught in the crossfire here but I wanted to mention that I was not 'raised' in this tradition but when I use it, I find that my first attempt to make my tests pass will often not work.  I find issues earlier resulting in higher code quality at an earlier stage of development.

Comment: @RobertHarvey would you mind to explain was Emergent Design?

Comment: @nerdlyist start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergent_Design#Emergent_design_in_agile_software_development

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I might start with a set of requirements, but those requirements are often fluid. And I actively resist silly requirements like "must use SQL Server" for example. The thing is "there's nothing at all magical about writing your tests first, other than it forces you to make your code more testable" is the killer feature of writing automated tests as you go. Easily testable code has to be loosely coupled. If suddenly the customer wants to use a no-sql DB, then only the data access layer need be swapped out. So the "architecture" isn't so important.

Comment: @JimmyJames If I could add an emoji it would be my head exploding. Thanks for this bit of information. I was super focused on TDD and let this one slid by.

Comment: @nerdlyist Sorry, I'm not sure which comment you are referring to but the first one was about using TDD.  I find it somewhat tedious but I do think it can result in higher quality code.  Unit tests in general are really helpful on multi-person projects because they help you avoid breaking other people's stuff.

Comment: @DavidArno I think your objection stems from not giving yourself enough credit as an experienced developer/architect. *Because you already know what module X looks like intuitively*, your tests will be driving your development in a good direction. An inexperienced developer with few to no intuitive notion of what a module should look like *before* writing the tests will build a well-tested, crappy module.

Comment: @nerdlyist Emergent design is the notion that you can change your architecture and add modules on-the-fly as-needed. It's the idea that you don't need detailed specifications for each module or interaction up-front. But, the emergent design proponents often fail to acknowledge that the details aren't usually needed up-front b/c practitioners of emergent design already know the details  ...

Comment: But even if you don't write all the tests at the start, how do you you are writing what you need? You might right some tests for a class that specify how it behaves, but then later on realise actually this was the completely wrong way to approach the problem, so the class needs to be changed considerably.

Comment: I still don't understand. The only difference between writing the test beforehand and writing it afterward is that you're making your design inflexible by writing it beforehand. Example, your test might say *x == y*, but then after you write the code to make the test pass you might realize that's actually prohibitively expensive, and you should really have been testing entire vectors for equality (e.g. *all(x[:] == y[:])*). Now how the hell did it help you to set the design in stone in the first place? Why not make the system and **then** write a test that actually makes sense for it?

Comment: @Mehrdad - why in the world do you think that tests are set in stone? They change as you code. And also, why are you testing the implementation? TDD should be black box testing. You call a method, give it arguments, and check the solution. How the method does it's thing internally SHOULD NOT be taken into account. You're testing the method contract, not internal implementation.

Comment: @Davor: what I'm saying is, what's the point of writing a test that you keep changing at will? Changing the test is extra work that you could completely avoid by simply writing the test once at the end. And the whole point of this example was to show that the actual implementation affects the usage and hence the tests.

Comment: @Mehrdad The goal is quick feedback. And not only on correctness. That's just a bonus that shouldn't be relied on, because you're bound to miss cases. Writing your test first gives you quick design feedback. You write the test without the code implementing it actually existing, so you can write your interface by wishful thinking. Then write the implementation. If the test is difficult to write, your design is probably flawed. Now, you _could_ get this feedback if you wrote the test after instead of before... But that would be after implementing one (or many) things that need rethinking.

Comment: @BartvanNierop: Hm, I see. So if it's about quick feedback, then it's just a speed thing? What if I don't particularly have anything pressing me to be coding as fast as possible? Would I not care then?

Comment: @Mehrdad The point is that you always have tests covering most of your code so you can change things and have a quick way to figure out if your changes broke something, and if they did, _what_.

Comment: @Cubic: I agree that's useful but I don't understand what that has to do with my question? I wasn't asking about *not* having tests at all, I was asking about writing each one *after* you've implemented the feature rather than before. That'd still be true regardless, right? 'cause you already know that 1 new test is failing, and the previous tests already exist there.

Comment: @Mehrdad If you're disciplined enough, yes. In your model, would you pass code that doesn't have tests yet through review if the author promises they're going to write the tests later?

Comment: @Cubic: Of course not? I wouldn't even be able to *tell* when they wrote it, all I can expect is for them to commit them together. So my point is there's no reason for them to do it before the functionality is implemented rather than after; I wouldn't even be able to tell.

Comment: @Mehrdad I certainly wouldn't force a programmer to write code in a certain order. You're right, if the commit is the same it doesn't matter. However, if you only write code for things which you have tests for you'll never produce commits which lack tests (tautologically). I think it's a bit easier to stay disciplined about the order of something (first test, then implement) than about causality (I implemented something, now I have to write a test for it).

Comment: The emergent design I was referring to does come, but I agree you do need someone steering it. This is again where pair programming comes in; you might have one half of the pair an "experienced" coder, the other a "junior", and in that case the experienced coder can drive the design as well.

Answer (score 86):

**Software is not a house.** Intuition is good, but understand that it isn't always correct.

> Break down all the specs into inspection I think I will need (see into the future).

This isn't accurate. In TDD, you're describing how you want to use the code. The specs say "There must be a house, with a way to enter it." The test then says "Hey, I want to have a front door, with a knob." This is *far* less seeing into the future than starting with the implementation of building a doorframe, knob, keylock, etc. (or so the argument goes).

> Call the inspector back out daily (passing 2/100).

This isn't correct. You're not writing tests for the house. You're writing tests for the front doorframe, then making them green. Then tests for the door being solid, making them green. You should have *maybe* a dozen or so tests at most broken at any given time. Usually, it's closer to two to four.

Also, the "call the inspector out" analogy implies that it takes some amount of time for the person to come out and do their job. Running unit tests for a TDD iteration should *literally* take a few seconds.

> It seems like changes can be made faster and without the overhead TDD seem to create.

The overhead is less than you seem to be implying. A few seconds to run the tests maybe a half dozen times is inconsequential to the overall development time.

The problem of dev first is sometimes when you get to testing, you find out that there is a *big* problem. Like you put the bed next to the toilet and nobody wants to live there sort of problem. Things that take longer to fix than any sort of TDD overhead. Things that TDD would have caught, since TDD forces you to use your code from the start and think about how to interface with it.

> My professors in college were all about the idea of Tests then Code then Test.

All that said, TDD isn't that ubiquitous. Many places still do dev first and much of the purported benefits of TDD are overblown. What's important is that you make the tests and make them good. The order that you do the work is less important.

Comment: I understand that physical is different then code (very well used to do roofing). When I said specs I meant unit. So yeah you need to build a door. Lets say at first a normal door then you realize it was a sliding glass door. All that upfront cost of test building was for naught. It feel that TDD would almost deter from larger changes in that way.

Comment: @nerdlyist But the test shouldn't be that specific- it shouldn't ask "Is there a perfect normal door that I can open into the house with a counterclockwise twist to the handle 3 feet off the ground?", it should ask "I try to `open_the_door`, and expect to be met with an `open_door` (or `entry_allowed`, depending)"

Comment: +1 just for the last paragraph.  Your house examples really highlight how silly "religiousTDD"  can be.

Comment: @Delioth I see your point. Just making sure proper action are taken is what matters. So if there is an `open` it does not matter how it opens (slides or flips) but that it opens. This was very insightful.

Comment: "What's important is that you make the tests and make them good. *The order that you do the work is less important.*" I am a big fan of Test-Driven-Development (TDD) and advocate for it often. However writing code is messy. For more difficult, less well defined problems I typically have to write some code first before I can understand what are the requirements. Then I can write the requirements and then write the tests.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith wouldn't you be writing the documentation at that point not the requirements.

Comment: Because TDD puts in the perspective of the *user* of the code, [in best-case] it promotes better interfaces. For example, when I call `open_door` I shouldn't have to pass a flag for `toilet_flushed`; so I don't write my test that way and therefore my code doesn't have these "rough edges." Code written entirely without sufficient regard for how it is called often has weird interfaces or assumptions/preconditions.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence. The original question might as well be asking why microprocessors are not built the same way you build a Lego model.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith to put a name to it, I've heard that called "Spike & Stabilize"  and yes, it's a handy technique when discovering how to do something you don't know how to do yet.

Comment: "Running unit tests for a TDD iteration should literally take a few seconds. " - what should I do if they're faster?

Comment: @JanDvorak faster than a few seconds? Find something else to worry about?

Answer (score 13):

The similarities between building a physical thing and writing software are pretty minimal.

That said, there's one massive distinction worth pointing out:

**There's a difference between "authoring a test" and "executing a test."**

In the example of building a house, the requirements and tests *do* precede the physical buildout. And portions of the test suite are run *continuously* -- by multiple agents even! When the builder picks up a 2x4, he immediately and automatically "tests" the unit against his notion of "what a sound 2x4 looks like." He doesn't author requirements after he picks it up; he runs pre-existent checks on it.

Likewise for an assembled wall, an electrical box, the plumbing, etc -- the tests/requirements already exist; they get run implicitly and automatically by the trained eyes of everyone on the job *continuously*. Another suite of pre-existent tests are executed when the inspector visits. If the units were not built to pass those *pre-existent* test, they fail.

And likewise for the structure as a whole. The plans pre-exist the buildout. At every step of the way, the engineers are working towards a pre-existent set of conditions that the structure will ultimately be *tested* against when the buildout is complete.

That said, not every physical project needs to be preceded by a huge suite of tests. If you go to your workshop and start putting wood together for a toybox or something, letting your intuition and creativity guide you, that's not rigorous TDD woodworking. In that case, you're basically relying on the physical laws of the medium and your rough expectations to validate the work (i.e., "if it compiles and it works, it's good!").

And that's OK. Not everything needs to be preceded by rigorous tests.

**tl;dr**

Even though construction != writing software: Construction does operate in a test-driven fashion. The "passing" conditions for every unit *do* precede their buildout.

Don't conflate "executing tests" with "writing tests."

Not everything needs to be TDD.

Comment: I get code != physical its an analogy. But this actually clears up a little more for me. As my other comment point out I am wondering if this create the test first hinders the desire to go back and make larger changes now?

Comment: @nerdlyist In a way, yes. But, if your tests are checking the "right" things, it's a "hinderance" you *want*.

Comment: Going back to the house analogy: If your client suddenly wants to swap in a different style of door, and it doesn't have the same dimensions, requirements around the door and opening dimensions will change, and the work require to change those "tests" should mirror the work required to make the implementation change. But, there are a lot of tests that *won't* change: The door must open and close, lock, and be P% airtight in the opening when closed, etc... Lots of tests that don't change that "hinder" physical changes *appropriately*.

Comment: As I start to come around now it would also seem that the door could be a parent and then child classes would need there own. One could be the sliding glass door. This make a lot more sense now.

Comment: @nerdlyist Please see me edits too. I think I overlooked a core aspect of your question.

Comment: If I could +1 again I would that last bit is helpful to consider. Not everything needs a test. Also, rereading it made me think maybe I am fusing TDD unit tests with integration and regression testing. The workers automatically testing is units the inspector is integration and regression testing is done when making larger changes.

Comment: @nerdlyist a good design is modular. if you realize that "whoops, we can't have a wooden door, we need a solid steel one!", then you don't change a whole bunch of things. you don't burn down your wooden door. you don't slowly rework the wooden door into a steel one. you build a steel door and you "unplug" the wooden one and "plugin" the steel one. "good TDD" (yeahyeah no true scotsman, sue me) prevents you from making changes that violate the specification you have created *for a single unit*. in this case, you MUST change things, or create something new. not a TDD issue.

Comment: @kai This was for sure one thing I was over exaggerating in my head. Since `door` could be a super class and have many children then there really is no waste in writing the unit. It will always be used. Even if the glass door is not used right now it maybe down the road and good thing that intern has the old tests for it.There is defiantly nothing to burn down.

Comment: @nerdlyist Integration and regression tests can be done test-first too. Doing so doesn't *quite* fit the "TDD dogmatists" development cycle, but the result is largely the same: You end up with testable code, with minimal extraneous code, and tests that actually validate what they claim to. Testing *after* you write the code can make accomplishing any or all of those those things a bit harder. Not at all impossible, but *potentially* more difficult.

Answer (score 11):

You have fallen into the trap of believing the nonsense idea that writing software is analogous to building a house. It isn't. It's more analogous to creating the architects drawings and the structural engineers calculations.

Now with real houses, the architect creates those plans up front. Then you call in the builders, who start building, run into problems, have to amend things, get building control in, who want changes, etc. Then at the end, the architect comes back and charges you more to update his drawings to reflect what happened. This is a crappy way of doing things, but houses take a long time to build and are expensive, so it's the only practical way.

Things are better for software engineering. The equivalent to the building the house is having the compiler turn your code into an compiled unit of some sort (library, app, web app etc). It's very fast and cheap to do this hundreds of times a day. As a result, it makes no sense to repeatedly rebuild the house as you add features, and only call in the inspector (QA) at the end to test it. Instead, if you automate those checks, you can have the inspector re-inspect everything every time you rebuild.

Whether you follow strict TDD, or a more *test-orientated* approach of writing some code, then some tests, doesn't really matter. I prefer the first approach, others the latter. Pick the one that suits you. The important thing is that you create those checks as you go along. They help later when you want to change code around by warning you of breaks in functionality elsewhere when you change something.

Comment: I see you've dealt with Building Control then... :)

Comment: "This is a crappy way of doing things, but houses take a long time to build and are expensive, so it's the only practical way.": It is true that in software you can rebuild very quickly, but if you make a completely wrong decision at the beginning you may need a big rewrite later. Incremental design does not always catch this kind of problems: you move in small steps until you find yourself in a cul-de sac and you have to go back. There is not silver bullet.

Comment: @Giorgio -- big rewrites happen because single decisions are reflected in many places in the code. When the decision changes, then the code changes in a lot of places. Continuous refactoring mitigates this problem, by squeezing out duplication and limiting the amount of code reflecting a single decision. Good test coverage supports continuous refactoring.

Answer (score 7):

First and foremost **the upfront cost is not as high as you think it is**. Yes, you spend more time addressing testing than if you do no testing. But if you do a "test after" method what are you really wasting? Let's say TDD takes 10 hours, and DDT takes 6 hours. Your "extra" upfront costs are only 4 hours. Now if you apply a code metric or requirement like 90% coverage, then your TDD and DDT become even closer in costs.

**You will write less buggy code with TDD.** Even if it's just because you have spelled out the requirements as a test, at the end of the day you can prove that your code is doing exactly what you wanted it to do. Now maybe you wanted it to do the wrong thing, but that's not a bug that's a change request. This is important. It's easier to "sell" a product that is working, but could work differently/better, then it is to sell a product that is perceived as not working. With TDD it's literally impossible to pass the test and write not working code. It is possible that you didn't understand the requirements, and that you wrote the wrong, but working code.

**TDD is better the older the code base gets.** Try refactoring without a test suite, or with a poorly implemented one. Even a simple change can introduce bugs. Having a test suite with good coverage ensures that as the product evolves it continues to function as it should. It also helps to highlight conflicting business rules (that happen over longer periods).

**You don't know it doesn't work.** Without a test suite you don't know if your code is working the way you think it is or if it just appears to be working.

```
var foo = function(in) {
    if(in == 0) {
      return true
    }
}
```

Now all over your application you call `if(foo()){ doStuff() }` What happens when I fix foo?

```
var foo = function(in) {
    if(in === 0) {
      return true
    }
}
```

**You should be refactoring and [DRYing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your tests too.** A good test suite is not hard to maintain. With well written atomic tests, I've rarely had to go back and change more than 1-2 of them at a time. When there have been larger changes to the test suite it's a giant red flag that something is not right.

> I just do not see how I should know all my methods and how things will work until my code is there.

Well, you're not supposed to. You're supposed to write a test that tests that some unit of work is done. If you feel like you're testing things that you can't possibly know about then you're thinking too big, OR testing is too small.

For example, you need to know that a door closes, and locks. I would test door.close() and door.lock() and that door.open() returns false when the door is locked. That is it. If your tests are door.lock() sets a flag in the database. Then you're testing too small. The test doesn't need to know how door.lock() works, just that it does.

Now if you're writing a test that says house.isSecure() returns true when all doors and windows are locked. Without looking at doors or windows first then you're thinking too big.

Finally, **You may be looking at too big a unit of work**. When you get your list of requirements, you should organize them so you're working on the smallest unit. Write the test for just that unit, then the code, then rinse and repeat.

In essence, your understanding (the list) of how TDD should work is off. You should never have 2/100 passing. You should have 1/1 passing, then 2/2 passing, then 3/3 passing, then 4/4 passing, and so on.

A revised list for you

1. Get all the specifications
2. Pick one specification
3. Test it
4. Code it
5. Test it
6. If tests pass move on to 7 else go to 4
7. If you have done all the specs, go to 8 else go to 2
8. Review the specifications with the consumer, and add new specifications where needed. If done correctly you shouldn't have to change any tests at all. Just add new ones. Sometimes requirements gathering can fall apart and you have to add tests that conflict with earlier tests, but you should rarely have to change tests.

Comment: I like this answer because it highlights the real advantages of TDD - making legacy codebases manageable. Many people who have only worked on the greenfield phase of a project don't see the benefit of TDD because it looks like it's just extra work. It really pays off when you have to upgrade and maintain an existing codebase. I wish that in school they would give you a project, then as soon as you get it working request a bunch of feature changes. That would more closely mirror reality and demonstrate the value of TDD.

Comment: I like this answer also.  Note that we tend to forget just how much time we actually spend manually executing tests:  edit, compile, step through to manually debug, repeat.  TDD automates much of this.

Comment: The thing that jumps out at me here is that it's important to note that when you write a unit test in TDD you're not writing a test for a piece of the client functional spec, you're writing a test for the behaviour of the unit as you - a programmer - have defined it in your brain, i.e. "this class should raise an event when X happens, let's write a test for that." This vague "your tests are your spec!" rhetoric is great when you already get TDD but to someone out of the loop it raises more questions than it answers.

Answer (score 4):

There are some keys that I feel the other answers are missing.

**Three Advantages**

First, the cost of error and cost of change is so incredibly different between software and a house that some rules may not apply.  For example, the cost of testing a physical structure is so high that you need a high degree of confidence of it working so as not to waste testing.  With software, if you can run a suite of unit tests in 1 - 5 seconds, then we have different options at our disposal.

Secondly, the purpose of executing a test that you expect to fail before writing the code-under-test is to verify the test itself.  Sure it can seem silly or wasteful.  But I've seen enough unit tests written in a way that will always pass, even when the code-under-test is broken.  That can easily happen when you write the code-under-test, test it manually, then write the unit test.  If you write a unit test, see it fail, then when you write the code needed to make it pass, and it passes, you know your test is sound.  If the code-under-test regresses, there is a reasonable chance your unit test will catch it.

A third advantage to TDD, not often mentioned, is that the resulting code size and complexity is often an order of magnitude smaller.  I have always prided myself on preferring simple and concise code.  Until I started practicing TDD.  TDD showed me that what I would have done prior would be excessive code.  Why does this happen?  Because you write a test, then write code to make the test pass.  When the test passes, you are done with it.  If you are in this mind set, it is difficult to accidentally write "extra" code.

(Extra code has been a problem I have observed in a product I used to work on.  Severe problems coming from code that nobody asked for, but some developer thought it would be cool.)

**Cost Analysis**

So in some ways, you are right.  We could not get away with this strategy when building a house.  It would be too expensive.  But software isn't a house.  Software is cheap.

An analogy with a house is the labor of assembling the house versus a software compiler.

In a non-TDD world, developers still iterate.  We follow a code -> compile -> run -> test cycle.  We're already in a model that deviates substantially from building a house.  If your construction people build a door frame, then build a door, then have to rebuild the frame because the door is too big for it, you'll have a cost problem.  Thus, you spend more time up-front to ensure you get everything perfect.  In programming, most projects can be compiled in seconds or minutes, so it doesn't matter if something is imperfect early on.  The cost of thinking trivial matters through ahead of time typically outweighs the cost of recompiling.  Thus, we recompile all the time.

TDD is the same principle, just rotated so the test goes up front.  If the testing can be made super cheap (so it all runs in seconds), then the cost of thinking through the big picture, perfect, overall solution in a single big-bang coding iteration outweighs the cost of refactoring.

**Except...**

There are some things in programming where these arguments don't hold up.  That is the purpose of architecture.  Identify and plan up-front concerns that will be more expensive to change later.  For example, you wouldn't pick a database on the fly without thinking about your needs, start building, and simply argue that you can change it later.  You need to think it through.

Comment: Great point on verifying the test!  Also:  when building a house, it's HARD to move a wall (and this leaves scars).  With software, moving code around is relatively easy - provided you have automated test to catch any unintended changes.

Answer (score 4):

I used to wonder about this a lot until I did a few projects of TDD. There is a very succinct and comprehensive explanation that popped to me while I did this:

When you write code you have to have some way of making sure the code does something meaningful. So you test your code. You can do ad hoc testing. However, testing works better if you think about how to test before you start doing things. So you design the test strategy before you go to testing.

Now since you are thinking about your testing strategy you might as well automate, at least a part of it... And behold you have some level of TDD. The fact that you write code till you pass the test is just normal. That's what you do anyway, write code till it works. It's just now easy to blast the tests.

For reasons beyond scope you don't write the entire thing in one go. So you don't design the tests in one go either. But basically that's what it is. Just better planning of testing, you don't always write test up front. Sometimes you add more as you progress and find bugs you didn't anticipate or make the test more robust later. And sometimes you may find yourself not designing tests, but find manual testing laborous so you do the tests later.

So TDD is just an extreme way at looking at how you validate your work.

Answer (score 4):

While this question already has an accepted answer I believe I have something to add, coming from a no-written-test style of design (all tests performed manually by "testers" following a test procedure) to TDD. These are just my personal observations, though I believe they're fairly universal.

When you're writing something new, something you've never done before, there is no significant difference between TDD and not doing TDD.

Generally what you'd do is write a small piece of code to explore an idea then add some hardcoded bits for "testing" and then compile and/or execute it. If it works you'd delete the hardcoded stuff and generalise the code by adding parameters, instance variables etc.

Think about it. That's exactly the same amount of work as TDD. The only difference is in TDD you'd write the "testing" bits separately in another file and not delete them at the end. In TDD **you keep your testing code**.

Of course, TDD being slightly more organised means that there is a bit more work figuring out how to separate the testing bits of code from your real code. But if you've written unit tests before you'll learn how to modularise your code for testing.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is agile all about the test-driven development (TDD) and not development-driven test (DDT)?

Just chirping in here because I find that the question suggests a fact ("agile is all about TDD") which I find rather objectionable. All answers seem to take this fact as granted. They are good answers if you assume agile is primarily about TDD (a.k.a., testing on the unit level).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development#Agile_methods lists a good dozen or more different development models.

I'd offer especially Behaviour Driven Development and Feature Driven Development as food for thought. Completely different beasts which *also* can lead to all the benefits of basic TDD but are a far cry from a simple red-green-refactor cycle.

So my answer ist:

- "DDT" (a.k.a., writing tests after or "on top" of the implementation) does not work for real-life-reasons; as soon as you get time or money pressure, the tests go out of the window; and just having tests for the benefit of having tests is rather meh anyways, IMO.
- Agile is *not* all about test-driven development (TDD) if you interpret that term as basically meaning "unit tests for all building blocks/classes" (which, at least according to Wikipedia, is the case). TDD is just one possibility of doing agile development.
- There are other methods, like BDD or FDD, which do a full-stack approach. You still write your scenarios up front, you still have a red-green-refactor cycle, and you still only implement until your scenarios are green, but your "tests" by definition excercise the whole software (by acting like user interaction) and never only one single unit.

I'd rather have an application with complete BDD/FDD coverage and no unit tests than one with complete unit test coverage and no full-stack tests.

(TDD has its place of course, for example in APIs, but that's not what we are talking about here.)

Again, I'm not trying to downtalk all other answers here, just pointing out that the question is formulated rather narrow, and the field has much more to offer.

Comment: I knew of the other but at the time writingthis ddt just seemed to make more sense. Care to elaborate on why TDD is better for API? How would using it on say a web client with MVC differ?

Comment: In APIs it is hugely important that they follow a very detailed _contract_; each method call must behave very predictable for the users (which are other programs) to use it correctly. This is where unit testing really shines. OTOH, in an application, it is most important for the features your humans users need to work as intended. Sure, your "internals" better be correct as well, but it is more important to have a good coverage of "end to end" functionality (i.e., from the UI right into the DB and back) instead of testing each individual method (which the human end users won't see anyways).

Comment: Of course, all is in different degrees here - it may make sense to have a smattering of unit tests here as well if you should have very complicated methods/classes somewhere (for example: calculating distances between geocoordinates); but the bulk (e.g., in business applications) is the overall workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't see it written this way often, much of the reasoning behind agile is that re-writing code is better than writing it well the first time.  Every time you re-write code you improve the code and improve yourself.  Getting it "Right" the first time tends to be slower and more brittle.

The house analogy isn't all that bad, but you have to think about how long we've known about house building vs how long we've known about software engineering--also the complexity of software engineering is closer to building a long bridge or 20 story tower than a house.  We should also consider that with new languages and tools being built it's like every builder wanted to build the building with completely different shapes, sizes and materials.  Complete chaos.

However, inspecting is not a good analogy to code testing. In software we aren't even to the point where we HAVE decent inspectors (Except your peers of various skill levels).  We also don't have regulations to inspect against except, perhaps, some mostly-arbitrary "coding standards" (which is more like testing the color of your paint and your lawn layout than the structure).

Test-first is more like you build a wall then you apply some pressure to it to ensure stability before lifting it and placing it on your house.  It's like measuring the window to ensure it will fit into the hole you left before trying to place it.

If you had to build a series of bridges without our centuries of previous architecture knowledge, patterns, regulations and math that we currently have to prove our bridges will work before we build them, you'd probably be testing and rebuilding your bridges a LOT.

Finally a non-analogy point--with software every time you are allowed to re-write a section of your code you improve both your code and your skill significantly.  Take every chance you can to re-write code.  TDD can be a great excuse.